# webform: redirect to modified result page

Tags: hooks, webforms

- After somebody submits a webform, he should be redirected to the "webform 
  result" (which is standard generated, but only accessible by clicking the 
  "webform results" tab as an admin).
- My module needs to hook into the "webform results", and add some simple custom PHP 
  calculations on top of that "webform result" (for example: if two 
  radio-elements have a certain value, a warning is displayed on top of that 
  result page)

Any ideas ?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have do some customization for this, use [hook_form_alter](https://www.drupal.org/taxonomy/term/33380)().

1. Create a custom module.
2. Create a result page in that module.
3. Alter the webform.
4. Do the calculation.
5. Sent the data to result page and show.

Example:

```
function  MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (strpos($form_id, 'webform_client_form_') === 0) {
    // webform_client_form_ (change this id with your form id)

   $form['#submit'][] = 'changeform_form_submit';

  }
}

function changeform_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  ... your submission logic ...
}
```

Comment: 1) Hi. Would it be better that after submission, the user redirected to node/<nid>/submission/<sid>? Here is all the submitted content visible.
2) Is this a better hook to use : webform_submission_page() ? Then I can add custom PHP text to this variable  : $output = drupal_get_form('webform_client_form_' . $node->nid, $node, $submission);